# How to pass only specific generic object to method, that takes first T as derived T<TK>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

Consider this code example:

We have abstraction for our UI system in the solution:

```
public abstract class Frame: IFrame {...}
public abstract class Frame<T> : Frame, IFrame<T> {...}
public abstract class Modal:Frame {...}
public abstract class Modal<T>:Modal,IFrame<T> {...}
...
```

New modal class can be declared as:

```
public class MyModal : Modal<T> {...}
```

Where T - data struct (or class) used to fulfill modal with some values.

To pre-init, adjust and show those UI we use static class, which contains such methods like:

```
public static T ShowFrame<T>(params) where T : class, IFrame
public static T ShowFrame<T,TK>(TK data, params) where T : class, IFrame<TK>
```

So now, to show MyModal we just call:

```
A.ShowFrame<MyModal>(...);
```

And with data:

```
A.ShowFrame<MyModal, MyModalData>(new MyModalData(...));
```

The problem is, how can we pass *strongly* typed data as our *TK* ?
We can write this: `A.ShowFrame<MyModal>(new AnyClassInSolution(...));`
Which is incorrect use case.

In the current system user can pass incorrect data, which will do nothing, but we want to avoid this use case and prevent long writing, for example:

```
A.ShowFrame<MyModal>(new MyModalData(...));
```

instead of

```
A.ShowFrame<MyModal, MyModalData>(new MyModalData(...));
```

And also make `TK` be only of T's data type.

I was looking into making a wrapper with callbacks to 'A', that will derive functionality to fluent api and split `Show<TFrame>` and `Set(data)`
Any other ideas, on how to make it straight in one method?

Edit:

Important thing to notice, we tried to use IData (or similar) interface for all data to be derived from, and instead of `public static T ShowFrame<T,TK>(TK data, params) where T : class, IFrame<TK>` there was `public static T ShowFrame<T>(IData data, params) where T : class, IFrame`

This solves the usability issue: `A.ShowFrame<MyModal>(new MyModalData(...));` is ok!

But the problem here - we want to support `struct` and `class` data input. (see struct interface boxing/unboxing issue) and the incorrect data use case was not solved.

Comment: What are '`params`' in `ShowFrame`? So far it seems it should work as expected, because the compiler selects a more specific overload of `ShowFrame`, inferring a correct type constraint for the `data` parameter.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I don't want to have to create one myself to be able to give you an answer. I don't have time to do that.

Comment: Enigmativity, you can paste the code I provided:
Create a static class, named A with ShowFrame methods inside

Comment: Ondrej Tucny, 'params' is just some layer definitions, adjustments and other non related to problem stuff

Comment: @Rdq - No, I can't. It won't compile. Can you please provide copy, paste, and compile code?

Answer (score 1):

Introducing a second `IFrame` descendant and clearly separating data-bound and non-data-bound classes into two distinct inheritance trees might provide an extra level of safety. Consider this:

```
public interface IFrameNoData : IFrame { … }
public interface IFrame<T> : IFrame { … }

public abstract class FrameNoData : IFrameNoData { … }
public abstract class ModalNoData : FrameNoData {...}
… other abstract classes remain the same …

public class MyModalNoData : MyModal { … }
```

And then the `ShowFrame` overload would clearly distinguish among data-bound and non-data-bound descendants:

```
public static T ShowFrame<T>() where T : class, IFrameNoData
public static T ShowFrame<T,TK>(TK data) where T : class, IFrame<TK>
```

Used like this:

```
A.ShowFrame<MyModalNoData>(); // legal
A.ShowFrame<MyModal>(new MyModalData(), …); // legal
A.ShowFrame<MyModalNoData>(new MyModalData(), …); // illegal
A.ShowFrame<MyModal>(); // illegal
```

However, this solution may be against the freedom of inheritance you might need in your case. I would also consider the following kinds of validation:

- run-time: add a type check for the type parameter, e.g. something along `(typeof(IFrame<TK>)).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`;
- compile-time: add a Roslyn-based custom code inspection that will catch invalid calls to `ShowFrame`

Comment: Please make this copy, paste and (attempt to) compile code.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's the same level of abstraction as the OP provided. It's about the principles, not syntax correctness. Can't see an issue here.

Comment: Its more about compile-time issue, can you share more info about adding custom code inspection?

Comment: @Rdq It's a fairly complex topic. Links at this page may be useful to get started: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-a-Custom-Analyzer-&-Code-Fix